# Kivy app with .kv file doesn't display

Tags: kivy

I am trying to modify this example: https://github.com/inclement/kivycrashcourse/blob/master/video14-using_a_screenmanager/after.py to make it work with a .kv file. This is my myscreenmanager.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

import time
import random

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ColourScreen(Screen):
    colour = ListProperty([1., 0., 0., 1.])

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def new_colour_screen(self):
        name = str(time.time())
        s = ColourScreen(name=name,
                         colour=[random.random() for _ in range(3)] + [1])
        self.add_widget(s)
        self.current = name

class MyScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyScreenManagerApp().run()
```

And this is my myscreenmanager.kv file:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
MyScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'first screen!'
            font_size: 30
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'goto second screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'second'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.new_colour_screen()

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'second screen!'
            font_size: 30
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'goto first screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.new_colour_screen()

<ColourScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'colour {:.2},{:.2},{:.2} screen'.format(*root.colour[:3])
            font_size: 30
        Widget:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.colour
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'goto first screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
            Button:
                text: 'get random colour screen'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.new_colour_screen()
```

After running the app nothing is displayed on the screen. No errors in console. Switching back to Builder.load_string displays the app as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Found my mistake: when using a .kv file the root widget needs to be surrounded in <>, like this:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<MyScreenManager>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:
```

Not sure why the discrepancy between load_string and .kv files, but it works now.

Comment: this is one way to fix it, the other is not oveloading build() (or returning the result of the super call), as the default behavior will use the root widget of the loaded kv.